One-liner PowerShell command to search entire Windows registry for a keyword
I'm trying to search the entire Windows registry for a specific keyword using PowerShell. I've tried various commands, but they either throw errors or run indefinitely without returning results. I need a one-liner that I can run in an elevated PowerShell terminal to find all traces of a specific keyword in the registry.
My attempts so far haven't been successful. For example:
Get-ChildItem HKLM:,HKCU: -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Property} | ForEach-Object { try { Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath -ErrorAction Stop | ForEach-Object { $_ | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Where-Object { $_.Definition -match 'MyKeyword' } | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]@{Path=$_.PSPath; Name=$_.Name; Value=$_."$($_.Name)"} } } } catch {} }

and
Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\,HKCU:\ -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object { 
    try { 
        Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    } catch {} 
} | Select-String -Pattern "MyKeyword"

These commands run without errors but never complete or return results.
What's an efficient one-liner PowerShell command to search the entire Windows registry for a specific keyword and return all matches?

@yy I am not sure if I fully understand you. Is it like one has to wait just longer? If that's the case how long? Or are you telling me it is just impossible to finish searching the registry?

It is possible, it just takes a very long.

$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Get-ChildItem HKLM:,HKCU: -Recurse |
Get-ItemProperty |
Where-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value -like "*MyKeyword*" } |
ForEach-Object {
    $property = $_.PSObject.Properties.Where({$_.Value  -like "*MyKeyword*" })
    [PSCustomObject]@{ Path = $_.PSPath -replace '^.*Registry::', '' ; Name = $Property.Name ; Value = $property.Value }
}

In my test it takes about 10 minutes.
You can put in one line like this:
$ErrorActionPreference='SilentlyContinue';Get-ChildItem HKLM:,HKCU: -Recurse|Get-ItemProperty|Where-Object{$_.PSObject.Properties.Value-like"*MyKeyword*"}|ForEach-Object{$property=$_.PSObject.Properties.Where({$_.Value-like"*MyKeyword*"});[PSCustomObject]@{Path=$_.PSPath-replace'^.*Registry::','';Name=$Property.Name;Value=$property.Value }}

